# monitor and watch multiple systems continuously

Tags: ssh, multiple-machines

As part of my work and collaborations and universities I've attended, I have access to many machines, about 13 or so. These are all Linux machines and I could ssh using my key-pair. There are a bunch of stuff running on these machines from time to time and also these machines are shared among users.

Is there a utility which could help me monitor these systems or something like take a stock of the systems as to what is going on on them.

I am looking for something lightweight which just needs a list of machine ids and a very minimal installation and could fetch me this information every morning when I log into my laptop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like Munin or Cacti to monitor the hosts via snmp. You could run it on one host that checks the hosts periodically and presents you a web page.

If you want to monitor and automatically alert you, you could use something like nagios.

Answer (score 3):

Nagios is a powerful monitoring system that enables organizations to identify and resolve IT infrastructure problems before they affect critical business processes.

Features (from [the Nagios website](http://www.nagios.org/about/features/))

- Comprehensive Monitoring
- Visibility
- Awareness
- Reporting
- Extendable
- Architecture
- Customizable Code

Can be downloaded directly from [here](http://www.nagios.org/download).

Answer (score 1):

- `cron` job that would collect the information you need and mail them to you (possibly encrypted)
- a shell script that connects to the machines in question via `ssh` (key-based authentication) runs a command and pipes it to a file on your machine, alerting you if something unexpected happens.